# Pivot status of booking by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot, recursive-query

A package can be booked between 2 dates, and the status of the booking gets updated by 2 users (0 as unconfirmed, 1 as pending confirmation, 2 as confirmed).
I am trying to display the status of a package over a period of time.

*We have the below tables*:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Packages](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Packages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bookings](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PackageID] [int] NULL,
    [fromDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [toDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [status] [int] NULL,
    [user1] [int] NULL,
    [user2] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Bookings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

*Some test data:*

```
insert into Packages(Name) values ('pack1')
insert into Packages(Name) values ('pack2')
insert into Packages(Name) values ('pack3')
insert into Packages(Name) values ('pack4')
insert into Packages(Name) values ('pack5')

insert into users(name) values('operator1')
insert into users(name) values('operator2')
insert into users(name) values('admin1')
insert into users(name) values('admin2')

insert into bookings(PackageID, fromDate, toDate, status, user1, user2) values (1,'7/1/2020','7/11/2020',0,1,null)
insert into bookings(PackageID, fromDate, toDate, status, user1, user2) values (1,'7/15/2000','7/18/2020',1,2,3)
insert into bookings(PackageID, fromDate, toDate, status, user1, user2) values (2,'7/6/2020','7/10/2020',1,1,4)
insert into bookings(PackageID, fromDate, toDate, status, user1, user2) values (2,'7/20/2000','7/25/2020',0,2,null)
insert into bookings(PackageID, fromDate, toDate, status, user1, user2) values (3,'7/13/2020','7/13/2020',2,1,3)
insert into bookings(PackageID, fromDate, toDate, status, user1, user2) values (3,'7/24/2020','7/30/2020',2,2,3)
insert into bookings(PackageID, fromDate, toDate, status, user1, user2) values (4,'7/5/2020','7/16/2020',2,1,4)
insert into bookings(PackageID, fromDate, toDate, status, user1, user2) values (5,'7/2/2020','7/8/2020',1,1,3)
insert into bookings(PackageID, fromDate, toDate, status, user1, user2) values (5,'7/22/2020','7/30/2020',1,2,4)
```

*I am trying to achieve something like this: displaying the booking status for July 2020*

```
Packages - 7/1/2020 - 7/2/2020 - 7/3/2020 - 7/4/2020 - 7/5/2020 - 7/6/2020 - 7/7/2020 - 7/8/2020 ... 
1        - 0        - 0        - 0        - 0        - 0        - 0        - 0        - 0        ... 
2        -          -          -          -          -          - 1        - 1        - 1        ... 
3        -          -          -          -          -          -          -          -          ... 
4        -          -          -          -          - 2        - 2        - 2        - 2        ... 
5        -          - 1        - 1        - 1        - 1        - 1        - 1        - 1        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably be simpler to put the dates in rows rather than in columns. If that's an acceptable solution for you, here is one approach that uses a recursive query to generate the dates, then joins. This assumes that there are not overlapping bookings for a given package:

```
with dates as (
    select '20207101' dt
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, dt) from dates where dateadd(day, 1, dt) < '20200801'
)
select p.id, d.dt, b.status
from dates d
cross join packages p 
left join bookings b 
    on  b.packageID = p.id 
    and b.fromDate >= d.dt
    and b.toDate   <  d.dt
```

You might want to adjust the inequalities on the dates according to the exact meaning of `fromDate`and `toDate` (I assumed an half-open interval).

If you actually want a pivoted resultset, then a method other than dynamic SQL is to use conditional aggregation over each day of the month, like so:

```
with dates as (
    select '20207101' dt
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, dt) from dates where dateadd(day, 1, dt) < '20200801'
)
select 
    p.id, 
    max(case when day(d.dt) =  1 then b.status end) [2020701],
    max(case when day(d.dt) =  2 then b.status end) [2020702],
    max(case when day(d.dt) =  3 then b.status end) [2020703],
    ...
    max(case when day(d.dt) = 31 then b.status end) [2020731]
from dates d
cross join packages p 
left join bookings b 
    on  b.packageID = p.id 
    and b.fromDate >= d.dt
    and b.toDate   <  d.dt
group by p.id
```

Comment: It _needs_ to be tabular, with package as first col, then each other col is a date, and the intersection is the status.
FromDate toDate is the range when the package is booked. So pack1 booked from 1 till 11 of July, date columns 1,2,3...11 will contain the status (0,1,2).
I tried second suggestion, it gave me a table with packageID and date columns, **but** it just gave me NULLs in the date columns, is it normal?
Plus we need to account for several months in the query. so just setting the condition on the day in the select query is actually not enough.
Not your usual task, huh :)